# iOS Swift 3 post issues

Tags: ios, mysql, django, swift3

I am using the following Swift 3 code in an iOS app to try to update a backend MySQL database:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://str8red.com/updateAPNS")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "devicetoken=gjhgjgjgkkgggkgkghgkgkhjg"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }
    task.resume()
```

When I run this code iOS acts as expected and returns a 500 error from the web server.  When I check the Webserver report I get the following error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /updateAPNS/
        "'devicetoken'
```

More confusingly the feedback suggests:

```
POST: No POST data
```

Should iOS not being posting the devicetoken variable as described in line 3 in the code above?  If not how do I access the devicetoken variable in my view?

My Django view is below incase it may help:

```
def updateAPNS(request, extra_context={}):

currentUser = request.user

currentUserID = currentUser.id

if not currentUserID:

    return HttpResponse("APNS is NOT Updated")

else:

    APNSUpdate, created = APNSDevice.objects.update_or_create(user_id=currentUserID,
                                                                     defaults={"user_id": currentUserID,
                                                                               "registration_id": request.POST['devicetoken']})

    return HttpResponse("APNS is Updated")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After using curl on the terminal to test a post request I got:

```
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

  <p>You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a &#39;Referer header&#39; to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
```

As soon as I saw this I just added `@csrf_exempt` above my view and everything worked perfectly.

For anyone wanting to know more about curl please head on over to:

https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Answer (score 1):

I use the following for posting data. This works for me

```
func postToUrl(url: String, data: Data, completion:(@escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with:request, from:data, completionHandler: completion)
    task.resume()
}
```

You could edit your code to use this function in this way

```
let postString = "devicetoken=gjhgjgjgkkgggkgkghgkgkhjg"
let postData = postString.data(using:.utf8)

postToUrl(url:"https://str8red.com/updateAPNS", data:postData) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your swift response.  I am very new so could you confirm where I put this and an example of it being called?

Comment: get the following error: Use of unresolved identifier 'postToUrl'

Comment: err that's the name of my function above. I renamed it in the edit

Comment: Oh yes, obviously.  I was trying something else and had removed your function temporarily.  I now have everything as you do BUT I get exactly the same error as the originally question :/ . Seems like there is something wrong at the other end perhaps?

Comment: That's a possibility. Can't help you with Django. I'm using a PHP backend and get POST data with file_get_contents('php://input')

Comment: Oh, so iOS won't actually send a POST response in it's true form?

Comment: You would need to add more to the URLRequest. You could try request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145263/discussion-between-alan-tingey-and-spads).